# I am using useForm in REACT JS but getting error INPUT value not working in first time ONCHANGE function in REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

i am Using ***REACT JS WITH HOOKS***

```
  import useForm from "react-hook-form";

  const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();

  <Form className="sign-up-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}> // form start


  <Col md={12} mb={3}>
                <label htmlFor="visatype">Visa Type</label>
                <div className="form-group">

                  <select className="custom-select form-control" 
                    name="visa_type_id"  
                    value={ VisaTypeId } 
                    ref={register({ required: true })}
                    onChange={e => setVisaTypeId(e.target.value)}
                    required>

                    <option value="">
                      Select...{" "}
                    </option>
                    {DynamicOptions(visaTypes)}

                  </select>
                  <div className="invalid-feedback">
                    {errors.visa_type_id && 'Visa Type is required.'}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Col>
```

I am using this `ref={register({ required: true })}` for validation i am selecting value from select getting error first time value is not selected

Comment: did you only copy a few parts of your code because there seem to be several issues with it? e.g. `setVisaTypeId` and `onSubmit` do not seem to be defined anywhere and you seem to be confusing the way you traditionally use react with inputs and the way that package expects you to do it: look at this demo from their repo https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-set-inputselect-value-c46ly they only ever pass a ref to the select input and they don't explicitly set an on change handler so it seems weird that you are?

Comment: thanks for reply.I want to set default value how i set in this way. Any suggession @TomFinney